# Redirect issue with Spring MVC and java 8

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring 4 MVC with tiles 3 and facing redirect issue in java8.

I have an controller to redirect request to some other external pages (Like I did in the sample code below). It is working fine till java 7 and only creating issues in Java 8.

Java 7 or older  --- Redirect Url became site `[url]/travel/home`

Java 8  --- Redirect Url became site `[url]/travel/travle/home`

**So in java 8 it is appending Request mapping from controller to redirect url.**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("travel")
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping("/redirectToSite")
    public String createFuncUnit() {
        return "redirect:travel/home";   
    }

    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String home() {
        return "home";   
    }

}
```

Comment: Doubt if it's really caused by version difference... Did you only change versions of the same project?

Comment: Yes. Application was working fine with Java 6 (compiled with JDK 6 and deployed in JRE 6 environment. Now we changed deployment run time to Java 8 and it start creating issue .

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it depends on JAVA version but you can fix it by adding `/`

```
@RequestMapping("/riderctToSite")
    public String createFuncUnit() {
        return "redirect:/travel/home";   
       }
```

then you will get :

> url/travel/home.

Comment: Yeah. Actually I was migrating an application from Java 6 to Java 8. I need to understand why it is working fine on Java 6 & 7. Did they changed anything for view resolver for Java version ?

Answer (score 0):

> Try this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/redirect", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView method() {
    return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("http://www.google.com"));
}
```